# 90s fantasy strategy PC game - wizards, warriors and bards

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I'm looking for a turn-based strategy fantasy game I played in the late 90s on a Windows PC.

From what I remember the game is based around managing a (medieval?) village with different classes of characters (including at least warriors, wizards and bards).

Each turn you could set each villager activities including farming and practicing their skills, maybe also construction, item making or gathering other resources (wood, etc.).

The village is routinely attacked by other humans and monsters, so the villagers needed to be fairly versed in their own skills, but they also needed to be fed.

There were turn based battles where you had to move your villagers and attack the invading forces. Warriors attacked with handheld weapons, wizards with magic and I think bards had magic for attack and healing.

Characters could be given items or weapons to improve their stats. I'm unsure if these items were made in the village or captured off enemies, possibly both.

I think the aim of the game was to build a strong enough army to attack the monsters on their own land.

I think the village was displayed in an isometric grid.

Comment: sounds like an Age of Empires rip off

Comment: @NKCampbell I played those too, but it's definately not any of those. You didn't build army units in this game but developed (possibly recruited) individual characters.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_of_Dragon_Pass

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks, but that's definately not it.

Comment: Some of these details match Lords of Magic, but wood wasn't a resource in that game (ale was, you needed to liberate breweries to supply ale to recruit troops).

Comment: Maybe it is series Heroes of Might and Magic ? In late 90 it should be 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroes_of_Might_and_Magic:_A_Strategic_Quest'

Comment: @someoneuseless no villager management that I recall in Heroes of Might & Magic series, though I don't know that I played them all.. whatever this game is, it sounds fun!

Comment: It could also be [Master of Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Magic) as you start with a small city and workers and fight monsters for resources and spells. You start with a wizard but you can choose other heroes along the game.

Comment: Coming back to this after a while. No it's not any of the games suggested so far.

Comment: Could it be Majesty? [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majesty:_The_Fantasy_Kingdom_Sim) It wasn't turn based but did have different types of units.

Comment: @SpikeHolden no it isnt majesty

Comment: You might check through this pretty complete-looking list: 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_turn-based_strategy_video_games

Comment: @MikeAndrews I've been through that list you linked, and although I can see many other games I used to play on that list, I still can't find the one I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While looking through an abondonware site, I found the game I have been looking for.

It is [Celtic Tales - Balor of the Evil Eye](http://www.abandonia.com/en/games/367/Celtic+Tales+-+Balor+of+the+Evil+Eye.html) released in 1995 for DOS.

The three character types are actually druids, warriors and bards. Both druids and bards could use magic spells.

This was indeed a turn based game with a turn based battle system.

Each turn you could set your heroes (villagers) tasks to help improve your village and skill levels. These include:

- Farming
- Cattle Herding
- Mining
- Chop Wood
- Cast magic spell
- Play hurling
- Build (improve your village power and defense)
- Rest
- Craft an item

Items are made in the village and can be given to heroes to improve one or more of their skills.

Heroes also represent a number of villagers and soldiers. The number of villagers and soldiers goes up inline with the development of the village.

The aim of the game was to take over the whole of Eire and then attack the Formors (monsters) stronghold on a nearby island. New areas can be taken if empty or can be conquered. You can also make other villages vessels (of varying levels) using diplomacy (tribute, trade and making requests).

Each village you manage can be attacked or raided by neighbouring villages or attacked by the Formors.

The main game screen is an isometric view of the village.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Congratulations on finding it! It looks linteresting.